# i am trying to configure Lexik JWT Bundle but i am getting error which is given below

Tags: mongodb, symfony

There is no extension able to load the configuration for "jwt_private_key_path" (in /var/www/html/EduboldPortalApp/eduboldportal/app/config/parameters.yml). Looked for namespace "jwt_private_key_path", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "doctrine_mongodb", "lexik_jwt_authentication", "fos_rest", "debug", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution" in /var/www/html/EduboldPortalApp/eduboldportal/app/config/parameters.yml (which is being imported from "/var/www/html/EduboldPortalApp/eduboldportal/app/config/config.yml").

There is no extension able to load the configuration for "jwt_private_key_path" (in /var/www/html/EduboldPortalApp/eduboldportal/app/config/parameters.yml). Looked for namespace "jwt_private_key_path", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "doctrine_mongodb", "lexik_jwt_authentication", "fos_rest", "debug", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution"

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the bundle has been added to the `app/AppKernel.php` ?

From the error it seems like symfony is not loading the bundle.